# using jquery autocomplete difficulty

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete but having dificulty to load the autocomplete in the textbox

My model is as follows:

```
Users = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in User.LoadSortedByName())
{
    Users.Add(item.Name+"\n");
}
```

View:

```
<p>@Html.TextBox("user", "")
 $(function () {
           $("input#user").autocomplete('@Model.Users');
});
```

---

**UPDATE - SIMPLIFIED ATTEMPT and STILL NOT WORKING**

_layout

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

View


  <p><input type="text" id="tags" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });


    });
```

Comment: @user281180 - Have you made any progress with this?

Comment: @Sergi, thanks for the example. I have tried a simple autocompletion example, and it seems that the autocomplete isn`t working at all. Please see the my codes, though i`m referencing the jquery.autocomplete.js, it doesn`t seem to work. Please see my work test as above, cant understand why it`s not working.

Comment: @Sergi, i`ve modified the codes, now with a simple test, it seems that the autocomplete isnt working at all. please see the new codes

Comment: I hope you realise that you've completely changed the question. I think you should have left you old question and added somethin like "UPDATE: ..."

Comment: @I don`t know what I did, and erased the question accidentally, however, the problem remains the same, autocomplete not working!

Comment: @user281180 - Are you using the jQuery autocomplete from the jQuery UI suite or the one from [bassistance.de](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)?

Comment: @sergi, the jQuery autocomplete from the jQuery UI suite , I just dowloaded the following /* * jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.11 * * Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about) * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses and referenced <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> and using the mvc3 jquery 1.4.4, but still not working

Comment: Mhm... I see you're using the [example on this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). Does the autocomplete demo work in there for you?

Comment: @There, it`s working, but not in project

Comment: Did you include the jQuery UI Core js library? It's required for all jQuery UI plugins. Try adding this line: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: I missed the jquery-ui.min.js. So it means that we dont need the jquery.autocomplete? Thanks, that was the answer.

Comment: Glad you could solve it. I'll update the answer to reflect the missing script reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should actually be attaching the autocomplete behaviour to your text box.

That said, the autocomplete version included in the jQuery library isn't totally straightforward if you ask me.

```
$("input#user").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        // define a function to call your Action (assuming UserController)
        $.ajax({
            url: '/user/GetUsers', type: "POST", dataType: "json",

            // query will be the param used by your action method
            data: { query: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label: item, value: item };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    minLength: 1, // require at least one character from the user
});
```

In your controller, define the following Action

```
public ActionResult GetUsers(string query) 
{
    var users = (from u in User.LoadSortedByName()
                where u.Name.StartsWith(query)
                orderby u.Name // optional but it'll look nicer
                select u.Name).Distinct().ToArray();

    return Json(users);
}
```

This implementation will not allow multiple values on your textbox; for examples on how to do that check the [jQuery autocomplete examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

**UPDATE based on final resolution**

Make sure you have a reference to the jQuery UI Core.

From the Microsoft CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

From the Google CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or download it yourself from the [official jQuery UI Page](http://jqueryui.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

I developed an html extension in the form of plugin, to use the jquery ui autocomplete but in a very simple and dynamic. the syntax was something like this here

```
     $@Html.AutoCompleteFor(model => model.Id, x => x.Code , "List")
```

I left all the source code available (suggestions are welcome) and a zip file containing all the necessary files.
Hope that helps!

Project URL
http://autocompletemvc.codeplex.com/releases/view/70140

Bin files
http://autocompletemvc.codeplex.com/releases/70140/download/259741

Comment: Your helper's dependency on partial views makes it almost unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you "load in the textbox" but more "attach autocomplete to" the textbox.  Try creation of a JavaScript array for the "answers" to the autocomplete.

It would also help to know if you use jQuery UI or the older plugin version of autocomplete.